# Display a image with imshow to be behind another plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy 2d array that I want to display as a bitmap image behind a regular lined plot.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from numpy import arange

figure = mpl.figure.Figure(dpi=70)

image = my_numpy_array #This is a regular float32 2D array created somewhere else

#I'm using a single sinus phase but the plot could be any (x, y) based function
x = arange(0, 360, 0.01)
y = 100*sin(pi*self.x/180)

subplot = figure.add_subplot(111)
self.subplot.imshow(image) #Doesn't work; how do I display the bitmap in the same subplot
self.subplot.plot(x,y)

figure.show() #I see the graphic and the sinus just fine but not my bitmap
```

Ultimately I would like something like this:

[image]

Where 0 corresponds to white and any value between 0.01 and 1 will appear according to a colorscale. Right now I see the sinus wave but not the dots.

Comment: deleting and re-asking an essentially identical question is discouraged, just edit your existing question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the code you provided works. You just have to remember that the images when plotted are shown on x axis from `0` to `image.width` and on y axis from `0` to `image.height`, so you have to align them:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a random image 200x360
image = np.random.randn(200, 360)


# Create a sin function from x = 0 - 360, y = -100 - 100
x = np.arange(0, 360, 0.01)
y = 100 * np.sin(np.pi * x / 180)

figure = plt.figure(dpi=70)
subplot = figure.add_subplot(111)
subplot.set_xlim(0, 360)
subplot.set_ylim(-100, 100)
subplot.imshow(image, extent=[min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)])
subplot.plot(x, y)

figure.show()
```

Which produces the image:

[image: image behind a plot]

Comment: Instead of offsetting the y-values of the sine-wave, it would be better to specify the argument `extent=[min(x),max(x),min(y),max(y)` when calling `imshow`, as this offsets the image rather than the plotted line. Also, instead of specifying the axis-limits explicitly, one can put `subplot.autoscale(False)` after the `imshow`.

Comment: Beat me to it nordev that was my next question: how to offset the image rather than the sin.